# How does the 'graphic views' on Hopper Disassembler work?

Tags: disassemblers, ios, hopper

I would like to understand better what is that information on "graphic views" at the inspector of Hopper Disassembler. I've checked the tutorial but it just skips this section.

[image: Entropy view]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you  post a screenshot and point out the parts you don't understand? (use the "edit" link)

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky i've just updated, can you take a look? Thank you very much

Comment: okay, this is better. Do you get any hints when you hover your mouse over the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) representation of the binary's entropy values (probably each pixel is averaged over some small byte range). It was likely inspired by this work:

https://corte.si/posts/visualisation/binvis/index.html